# Union from the values of a repeated nested key

Tags: typescript

How can I create a union from the values of the `bar` properties?

```
type Foo = {
  lorem: {
    something: {
      one: {
        bar: 'a';
      };
    };
  };
  ipsum: {
    something: {
      two: {};
    };
  };
  dolor: {
    something: {
      three: {
        bar: 'b';
      };
    };
  };
};
```

I want this:

```
type Result = 'a' | 'b'
```

Comment: Use a recursive mapped type? https://tsplay.dev/mL2K4w

Comment: please clarify more about your problem

Comment: You can also do it with a conditional type: https://tsplay.dev/w17zym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Oblosys and caTS, the answer is something like this:

```
type DeepValues<T, K> = K extends keyof T
  ? T[K]
  : T extends object
  ? DeepValue<T[keyof T], K>
  : never;

type Result = DeepValues<Foo, 'bar'>;
```

https://tsplay.dev/WKO1yW